# How to make rectangular photo of a book?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, distort

I try to make this photo rectangular. Borders of the page and vertical and horizontal lines should be linear. Ratio can be corrected later.

[image]

http://hpics.li/d6d43bc

Photoshop `Puppet Warp` couldn't help me.

Comment: Do you only want the INSIDE of the picture to be a bit more straight or the exterior sides as well? Also, how important is the document? Will be used for photocopies?

Comment: So you want the edges of the book to be completely straight? Why don't you just draw a shape with the pen tool or use the shape tool. I think the pages are almost completely white and you can create your own drop shadow. It is also best to re-write the copy for better results.

Comment: If the goal isn't to keep it as a photo, but rather use the text from it somewhere else, you should consider just rewriting the text.

Comment: @all I would like to reshape this page and many others from a captured book. The goal is to keep a readable version on computer/tablet without rewriting the content. (Make a ebook for a personal usage.)

Comment: I found another question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30948/best-way-to-flatten-a-curled-photographed-book-photograph

Comment: I'm always suspect of any book that has to start with "how to use this book".

Answer (score 3):

I would use an app on my phone called [jotnot](http://www.jotnot.com/scanner.html). It's one of many types of apps meant to be a photocopier. You load this page image, select the corners, and you're done. [image]

Of course, this solution is crude and nothing to do with graphic design. But it gets the result that it seems you are seeking.

Comment: It's a good solution! It would be great if we could adjust inside parts to make them straight e.g. the horizontal line under the title.

Comment: JotNot is a gem of an app. even will make the PDF for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to reshape this page and many others from a captured
>   book. The goal is to keep a readable version on computer/tablet
>   without rewriting the content. (Make a ebook for a personal usage.)

If it's for personal usage and you don't mind it not being perfect (and don't want to retype) then it's not that hard. This is a quick way to do it but the result is not perfect. If you want perfection, retype the text.

**1)** Simply use the crop tool in Adobe Photoshop and crop out the useless part first: everything outside the white area.

**2)** Then in Photoshop place some guides where the vertical and horizontal lines are.Place some guides too where your columns are. This is to help you align your "transform" to these guides.

**3)** Use the Free Transform (Command + T, or right-click on the layer and select Free Transform). The layer will be a background; double click on it to make it a normal layer.

[image: Example of free transform]

**4)** Additionally, to hide the jagged lines, erase them and redraw them with the Rectangular Marquee Tool (selection rectangle)

[image: Final]

**It's not perfect** but I did only ONE free transform to get to this. You can always align the very badly skew lines independently using the rectangular Marquee Tool (selection rectangle.)

You can also use the "Skew" to transform your text but if you do this on a very low resolution, it will make it look blurry very easily.

[image: Free tranform]

Comment: Third and last step will help me; fourth step is not necessary. I think I was looking for the Edit > Transform > Warp tool in order to suppress curled parts. Is there any tool capable to straighten a very distorted image like this one? http://hpics.li/98e1b6d

Comment: A brick.... applied on the binding part of your magazine to flatten it when you take a picture! But seriously, besides the transform tools in Photoshop, I don't know what would work better. With the warp transform you can change a bit the curves by using the handles but it won't do miracles. One thing I just tried that could be a shortcut for some files: In Acrobat Pro, go in View/Toolsets and select Default tools. Then try the Text Recognition. It straighten a bit the page already. Test here: http://i.imgur.com/Ga18h5v.jpg  Maybe you'll only need to skew the horizontal lines and boxes